# What does href="/" means in angular 2/ 4?

Tags: html, angular, href

the below code is in index.html in the angular app, where will this redirect to?

```
<body>
<base href="/">
</body>
```

Comment: please read router in angular docs. They have explained the purpose of base there.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#set-the-base-href

Comment: see quora  for such type of questions & answers . It Explained all Your basic queries [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-base-href-in-angular-2)

Comment: ok i will look into those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your root base path, all the resources and assets in your application are referenced based on this.

By default base URL is set as (/) or root.

This means that your app would start from root folder i.e locally it would consider localhost:3200/ and on server it would consider root folder.

Comment: I think this community is not for those who want to learn and explore new tech skills, maybe I am at the wrong place

Answer (score 4):

The base href="/" tells the Angular router what is the static part of the URL. The router then only modifies the remaining part of the URL.